# Isues with date format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am working with a dataset that contains dates in the American M-D-Y format.

When I load the dataset into a Pandas data frame and change the column type to the date format the dates get messed up.

Example: In the data set the first date is written as (11/04/2015) which means the 11th of April 2015. But when I convert to DateTime and use sort the data frame by the date the first date is (01/08/2015) which is incorrect. How can I change the column to DateTime and not get this messup?

dataset example :

```
IDX_CUSTOMER_ITEM_CODE  IDX_COMPANY QtySold TotalOnHand Date
0   131 1   3   26  11/04/2015
1   134 1   3   17  11/04/2015
2   137 1   3   114 11/04/2015
3   140 1   3   18  11/04/2015
4   179 1   1   21  11/04/2015
... ... ... ... ... ...
1048570 1059    10  0   23  04/03/2017
1048571 1075    10  3   14  04/03/2017
1048572 2135    10  2   4   04/03/2017
1048573 1035    10  2   3   04/03/2017
1048574 1038    10  0   5   04/03/2017
```

The first date is 11 of April 2015 and last 4th march 2017.

When I do:

```
transactions['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(transactions['Date'])
```

The oldest date becomes 01/08/2015 and the latest 31/12/2016 which is incorrect. so tired:

```
transactions['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(transactions['Date'], format = '%dd-%mm-%yy')
```

Got the following error:

```
time data '11/04/2015' does not match format '%dd-%mm-%yy' (match)
```

Comment: You'd need to show how "you convert to DateTime" in order for us to help. A reproducible dataset and code is even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `dayfirst` parameter:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Output:

```
0   2015-04-11
1   2015-04-11
2   2015-04-11
3   2015-04-11
4   2015-04-11
5   2017-03-04
6   2017-03-04
7   2017-03-04
8   2017-03-04
9   2017-03-04
```

Answer (score 0):

You format is wrong. You can refer to [Python strftime reference](https://strftime.org/) for the meaning of `%` code.

```py
transactions['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(transactions['Date'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')
```

```
print(transactions['Date'])

0   2015-04-11
1   2015-04-11
2   2015-04-11
3   2015-04-11
4   2015-04-11
5   2017-03-04
6   2017-03-04
7   2017-03-04
8   2017-03-04
9   2017-03-04
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: @YussufAbdirizak I have added a sample output. I think it is the same with *The first date is 11 of April 2015 and last 4th march 2017*. `transactions['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(transactions['Date'])` seems not distinguish month and day correctly. Use `format` to tell it explicitly.

Comment: @YussufAbdirizak Your requirement seems conflicted. *contains dates in the American M-D-Y format* and *11/04/2015 -> 11 of April 2015* are not the same.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it by telling DateTime through format what was the actual date format(m-d-y) and all is good now